Проблема с принятием на сообщением на WebSocket
Пытаюсь сделать чат на Spring между 2 пользователями, но сообщения отправляются, но не приходят:
var socket = new SockJS('/chat');
var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
var currentUserId = document.getElementById("currentUserId").value;
var receiverId = document.getElementById("receiverId").value;


stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);


    var receiverId = document.getElementById("receiverId").value; // Получаем receiverId


    stompClient.subscribe('/user/' + receiverId + '/queue/reply', function(messageOutput) {
        var message = JSON.parse(messageOutput.body);
        var chatDiv = document.getElementById("chat");
        var newMessage = document.createElement("div");
        newMessage.innerHTML = "<strong>" + message.sender + ": </strong>" + message.content;
        chatDiv.appendChild(newMessage);
    });
});



function sendMessage() {
    var messageContent = document.getElementById("message").value;
    
    var message = {
        sender: currentUserId,   
        receiver: receiverId,    
        content: messageContent  
    };


    stompClient.send("/app/sendMessage", {}, JSON.stringify(message));


    document.getElementById("message").value = '';
}

Подписка успешно проходит и мне кажется ошибка где-то на стороне сервера, но не могу найти где.
Конфиг:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue", "/user");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS(); 
    }
}

Контроллер
    @MessageMapping("/sendMessage")
    @SendTo("/queue/reply") // Сообщение будет отправлено только получателю
    public Message sendMessage(@Payload Message message) {
        return message;
    }


Решил проблему, изменил контроллер:
@MessageMapping("/sendMessage")
public void sendMessage(@Payload Message message) {
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/user/" + message.getReceiver() + "/queue/reply", message);
}

